# How many wives and how many secondary wives (pilagshim) did King David have?

Tags: king-david

I read he had 18 wives, is that 8 wives and 10 pilagshim?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but highly relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-J6YxtpoHuk This video tries to give King Davids turbulent intimate life a bit of Chassidus

Answer (score 3):

[Rabbi David Levi](https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A/) says that he had 8 wives and 10 Pilagshim.

Answer (score 2):

The Seder Hadoros HaKotzair p.28 lists that he had 18 wives (and lists some of the more well-known - it is worth noting that he counts Eglah and Michal as being the same person see [Sanhedrin 21a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.21a.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

[image]

Some sources in Nach are:

1. Michal ([Shmuel 1 - 18:27](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.18.27?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
2. Avigail ([Shmuel 1 - 25:42](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.25.42?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
3. Achinoam ([Shmuel 1 - 25:43](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.25.43?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
4. Ma'acha ([Shmuel 2 - 3:3](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.3.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
5. Chagit ([Shmuel 2 - 3:4](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.3.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
6. Avital ([Shmuel 2 - 3:4](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.3.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
7. Eglah ([Shmuel 2 - 3:5](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.3.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
8. Batsheva ([Shmuel 2 - 12:24](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.12.24?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

And then as has been mentioned in the comments there were 10 concubines ([Shmuel 2 - 15:16](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.15.16?lang=bi)) - One of which as the Seder HaDoros lists, is Ritzpah (Yerushalmi Sanhedrin 2:3)

Comment: There is also this verse which may refer to other wives not mentioned in your list https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.12.8?lang=bi